# How can I get tapped View Elements using Android Accessibility Services?

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I tried to create an Android Accessibility Service to detect all Elements in an App and show Accessibility Information like Content Description or Labeled by.

At the moment I can, using the AccessibilityService Class, log the Node Hierarchy when opening an App:

```
switch (evt.getEventType()) {
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED: {
                    logNodes(getRootInActiveWindow(), 0);
```

But **how can I get the information only of a View Element that was tapped/clicked?** Is there an easy way, using Accessibility Events to do so?

If I use for example AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED I can detect clickable View Elements like Buttons or Checkboxes by clicking on them. But is there an Accessibility Event to get non clickable View Elements like Text-Views?

I know that Google's talback speaks whatever you tap on, using AccessibilityServices, and it doesn’t matter if it is a button or any other view Element.